# Onelogin Internal Provisioning Error While provisiong a user from a group

Tags: group, onelogin, scim

When the "group" endpoint is called, it shows that a user is part of a group. However, the user is not provisioning in the application. So, the user is supposed to be in the group, but because of the “Internal Provisioning Error” in the application, the user isn't being displayed correctly in the group response.

[image]

[image]

1- Added the group parameter to my OneLogin app.
2- Added the OneLogin role and link it to my OneLogin app.
3- Associated my OneLogin app with one OneLogin user I added to the role.
4- Added a rule to my OneLogin app that creates user groups in the App based on the OneLogin role.
5- Provisioned the users I linked to my OneLogin app.